# Redirect to an other page or show a dialog message if something went wrong

Tags: jsf, primefaces, javabeans

Currently developping a Java8 web app with JSF and primefaces, and I am succeeding in posting a new form with an Oracle Database. But I think, if there is an error for a reason or another, I would like to inform the user by, instead of redirecting him to another page, just showing him a dialog and say something like "something went wrong, try again later".

So is it possible ? I think I have to combine the following commandButton that output a dialog message with the other commandButton in my form.xhtml. But action and onclick a note compatible, aren't they?

Edit : a growl message could also fit if it is easier

```js
<p:commandButton value="Valider l'enquête" type="button" onclick="PF('dlg2').show();" icon="fa fa-plus-circle"/>
    
<p:dialog header="Modal Dialog" widgetVar="dlg2" modal="true" height="100">
    <h:outputText value="This is a Modal Dialog." />
</p:dialog>
```

form.xhtml

```html
<h:form>
<div id="postFormulaire" class="ui-g">
 <div class="ui-g-5"></div>
 <p:selectOneMenu id="comiteMenu" value="#{enquete.idComite}"> 
  <f:selectItems value="#{sessionScope.utilisateur.comites}" var="comite" itemLabel="#{comite}" itemValue="#{comite.idComite}" />
 </p:selectOneMenu>
 <div class="ui-g-5"></div>
 
 <ui:repeat id="repeater" value="#{enquete.questionsReponses}" var="questResp" class="ui-g-12">  
  <div class="ui-g-12"><b>#{questResp.question.titreQuestion}</b> #{questResp.question.question} </div>
     
  <div class="ui-g-1"/>
  <p:inputTextarea class="ui-g-9" id="reponse" value="#{questResp.reponse.commentaire}" label="f"></p:inputTextarea>
  <div class="ui-g-2"/>
     
  <div class="ui-g-2"/><p:separator id="separator" class="ui-g-8" /><div class="ui-g-2"/>
 </ui:repeat> 
 <div class="ui-g-5"/><p:commandButton id="validerForm" class="ui-g-2" icon="fa fa-plus-circle" value="Valider l'enquête" 
           action="#{enquete.postNewForm()}" process="@form"></p:commandButton><div class="ui-g-5"/>
</div>
</h:form>
```

```js
@Named
@RequestScoped
public class Enquete  implements Serializable {
 private List<QuestionReponse> questionsReponses;
 private int idUser;
 private int idComite;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
   questionsReponses = new ArrayList<>();
   List<Question> questions = EnqueteDAO.loadQuestions();
   for(int i=0; i< questions.size();i++) {
    this.questionsReponses.add(new QuestionReponse(questions.get(i), new Reponse(questions.get(i).getIdQuestion())));
  }
  }

 //validate form
 public String postNewForm() {
  boolean success = EnqueteDAO.create(questionsReponses, idComite); // this method will return a boolean true if the request has succeeded and false if it did not
  return (success ? "../admin.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" : "#" ); //if it succeeded but what to return if not 
 }
}
```

Comment: See my answer in this question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51392946/how-to-execute-or-not-an-ajax-call-based-on-a-condition   It is almost the exact same problem you have.

Comment: Thank you I will check it :)